# sipe (plugin pidgin-gaim) unable to find libpurple headers

Tags: compiling, pidgin, pkg-config

I downloaded : pidgin 2.10.6 and sipe 1.14.1 from sourceforge.

I install pidgin with the following command in the folder of pidgin (2.10.6):

```
./configure --prefix=/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe --disable-screensaver --disable-gtkspell --disable-vv --disable-meanwhile --disable-avahi --disable-nm --disable-tcl

make
make install
```

it works fine and i can launch pidgin with `/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/bin/pidgin`

then i tried to install the plugin sipe but in the folder of sipe (1.14.1) the command:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe
```

returns :

```
checking for PURPLE... no 
checking for TELEPATHY_GLIB... no
configure: error: at least one plugin must be selected

If you didn't use a --enable option then please check that you have
the headers for the packages "purple" or "telepathy-glib" installed.
```

I add in my environment variable `PATH` the folder `/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/bin` and i export `PURPLE_LIBS="/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/lib"` but the result is the same.

And in the folder `/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/include/libpurple` the headers are here :

```
account.h conversation.h debug.h .... upnp.h
```

Am I missing something or how can I tell to sipe where libpurple is.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should install `libpurple-dev` with `apt-get`. That should solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler/linker where to look for the libraries. The `--prefix` option only tells the build system where to place the **resulting stuff**, not where to look for any dependencies.

Usually this can be done either by setting some environment variables or with an option for the `configure` script (preferred). Check output of `configure --help` for options like `--with-purple=path` which allows you to tell the buildsystem where compiler/linker should look for header files/libraries. Sometimes there are two options `--with-libXYZ-header=` and `--with-libXYZ-libs=` sometimes there is just one - in the former case you specify the full path to headers/libraries, in the latter just the parent directory (`/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe` in your case).

If the options fail, resort to `CFLAGS` for C compiler, `CXXFLAGS` for C++ compiler, `CPPFLAGS` for the C preprocessor, and `LDFLAGS` for the linker (`ld`). In your case adding:

```
-I/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/include -L/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/lib
```

to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` should do the trick (note that you might need to use `lib64` instead of `lib` if you are on 64bit system though).

As a side note, these environment variables are *not* handled by the compiler itself, rather they are customarily used in Makefiles (and it's usually considered a good practice to use them whenever you write your own build system).

Comment: I made progress. I set some environment variables : `export PURPLE_CFLAGS='-I/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/include/libpurple/` and `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/lib/pkgconfig/"` but now i struggle with the lib64 as your note mentioned. I can't find the library purple for 64 architecture. I have the following error after the commande `./configure --prefix=/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe` : `checking for PURPLE... yes
checking for 32- and 64-bit header conflicts... configure: error: in '/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/pidgin-sipe-1.14.1':
configure: error: conflicts found.`

Comment: @TonyMorris Hm... the error should be slightly better describe in `config.log` - it should be possible to look for it by these error messages. It should be towards the end of the file, but not directly at the end (that is where general configuration of the `configure` script that wrote the log).

Comment: `conftest.c:24:18: error: glib.h: No such file or directory
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
In file included from conftest.c:25:
/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/include/libpurple/cipher.h:79: error: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'gchar'
/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/include/libpurple/cipher.h:79: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
/home/tony/soft/pidgin_sipe/include/libpurple/cipher.h:82: error: expected ';' before 'void'`  and i have a lot more on `cipher.h` (about 40) and some more on `conftest.c`

Comment: @TonyMorris see whether `conftest.c` still exists (that's the file that configure uses to test compilation with various options/libraries) and try to compile it yourself (with the same flags `configure` tried to use), and proceed from there. If it doesn't exist any more, you might need to put something into the `configure` script that would save the contents of the file before it is removed.